# problem with combination of beamer and rand from tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, random

When running the enclosed MWE my problem is to see at the first glance (I hope so at least): I would like to place the various words with each visible-step at random places
on the slide. But if a word is placed I would need it to stay put at its place. How do I achieve this? Many thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\TikZsetword}[1]{%
   \visible<+->{%
   \pgfmathrand
   \let\x=\pgfmathresult
   \pgfmathrand
   \let\y=\pgfmathresult
   \node at (\x*3cm,\y*2cm) {#1};
   }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschleistungsdichte}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschtemperatur}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschzahl}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\pgfmathsetseed` at the beginning of every slide. (That is, using it once at the beginning of the frame.) By the way, the default value is `\time`*`\year`. Or consider `\pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathsetseed\pgfmathresult`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex` we know that `\pgfmath@rnd@z` stores the current number. So we can wirte

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathsaveseed{
    \xdef\pgfmath@savedseed{\pgfmath@rnd@z}
}
\def\pgfmathloadseed{
    \xdef\pgfmath@rnd@z{\pgfmath@savedseed}
}
```

and test it by

```
\begin{frame}{first test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsaveseed
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult ~-~-~-~should be
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathloadseed
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult ~-~-~-~the same
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathloadseed
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult ~-~-~-~as here
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Next we want to used it at the beginning of every slide, so

```
\def\beamerframeseed{
    \only<1>{\pgfmathsaveseed}
    \only<2->{\pgfmathloadseed}
}
\begin{frame}{second test}
    \beamerframeseed
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
        \item \pgfmathgeneratepseudorandomnumber\pgfmathresult
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image][image]

Notice that `1438536715` appears again. This must happen.

Now go back to your Question

```
\begin{frame}{foo}
    \beamerframeseed
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \TikZsetword{Rauschleistungsdichte}
        \TikZsetword{Rauschtemperatur}
        \TikZsetword{Rauschzahl}
        \TikZsetword{Rauschspannung}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit that I am deeply impressed. Thanks a lot, this really does the trick! Especially your explanation is very instructive.