# how to fix the positions of random points in latex?

Tags: beamer

I'm using the presentation mode in beamer. There's a frame about random stars distributed in a rectangle. I made a pause effect on that slide. However, the next frame would give me a different distribution of random stars. How can I fix the positions of that random stars and also keep the pause effect??

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{rose}}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\filldraw[fill= blue!40, very thick,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);\pause
\draw plot [blue!80, only marks, mark=star, mark size=3, domain=0:6, samples=300] (\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
\draw[color=red!80,very thick] (2,1) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you want to call `\pgfmathsetseed{n}` to explicity set the initial seed for the pseudo-random number generator - then it will be the same each time it's drawn.  `n` should be an integer.

Comment: The macro mentioned by @Thruston should be invoked inside of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution? Write your TikZ picture to a file with the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package or the exteranalize TikZ library, then bring it in via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works very well! Now the positions are fixed!@Thruston.

Comment: Yes, this is another way to make it happen. Thank you so much, too. @MikeRenfro

Comment: Not to show off, I have answered [a similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230935/problem-with-combination-of-beamer-and-rand-from-tikz/231049#231049). Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Some explanation could be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230935/problem-with-combination-of-beamer-and-rand-from-tikz/231049#231049). I will do it again because your example is more interesting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathsaveseed{\xdef\pgfmath@savedseed{\pgfmath@rnd@z}}
\def\pgfmathloadseed{\xdef\pgfmath@rnd@z{\pgfmath@savedseed}}
\def\beamerframeseed{\only<1>{\pgfmathsaveseed}\only<2->{\pgfmathloadseed}}
\begin{frame}
    \beamerframeseed
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \filldraw[fill= blue!40, very thick,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);\pause
        \draw plot[blue!80,only marks,mark=star,mark size=3,domain=0:6,samples=60](\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
        \draw plot[blue!80,only marks,mark=star,mark size=3,domain=0:6,samples=60](\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
        \draw plot[blue!80,only marks,mark=star,mark size=3,domain=0:6,samples=60](\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
        \draw plot[blue!80,only marks,mark=star,mark size=3,domain=0:6,samples=60](\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
        \draw plot[blue!80,only marks,mark=star,mark size=3,domain=0:6,samples=60](\x,{0.5*6+0.5*rand*6});\pause
        \draw[color=red!80,very thick] (2,1) circle (0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why don't you simply fix the seed?

Comment: @percusse Image that you are working in `handout` mode (`\pause`'s inactivated), where a beamer document is nothing but an article with specific paper size. Caring about seeds, in this case, is unnecessary and ... umm ... unromantic? So I would like to keep that romance in every mode. One may also write `\only<1,3>{\pgfmathsaveseed}\only<2-4>{\pgfmathloadseed}` to achieve something fantastic.

Comment: That explains perfectly my mere existence on this site too :) I meant as a mechanism you can set and unset the seed and it will result in the same mechanism. Didn't mean as a criticism :)